How to inject userManager inside the DbContext constructor?
I'm using IdentityDbContext and I have a SeedData class that I'm using inside the OnModelCreating method to seed the database using the initial migrations as follows:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    //
    //
    SeedData seedData = new(_userManager);
    seedData.SeedWebsiteAdmins(modelBuilder.Entity<WebsiteAdmin>());
    seedData.SeedCompanyAdmins(modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyAdmin>());
    //
    //
}

This SeedData class requires a parameter of type UserManager inside its constructor because it needs to create the new users as follows:
public async void SeedWebsiteAdmins(EntityTypeBuilder<WebsiteAdmin> entity)
{
    var superAdminLogin = new ApplicationUser()
    {
        Name = "Name",
        Email = "Email",
        UserType = UserType.WebsiteAdmin
    };

    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(superAdminLogin, "{password}");

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(superAdminLogin, RoleNames.WebsiteAdminRole);
    }

    var superAdmin = new WebsiteAdmin()
    {
        Id = SuperAdminId,
        WebsiteAdminLoginId = superAdminLogin.Id,
        MaxServiceDiscount = 100,

    };

    entity.HasData(superAdmin);
}

I've tried injecting the UserManager inside the DbContext constructor, but it's causing the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`3[RepositoryProject.DomainAuth.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.Guid]'

How can I inject the UserManager in the DbContext constructor without causing any error?
Or is there a way to create the identity user without using the UserManager so I can delete the dependency from the SeedData class and hence I wouldn't need it inside the DbContext?

In fact, put seeding logic code inside OnModelCreating is a pit of fall. In production environments, if the app is scaled out into multiple instances, race condition problem may appear. The effort addressing this issue is not small. Your current issue and potential issues can be avoided by create another new console app taking responsible to seed data only.

I'll try to address these issues when I want to scale up my app. But for now, it's not a concern for me. @NguyễnKỳDươngTrường

If you want to use migrations to seed data via model, the only way I found is to use HasData API with user data from db (I created first by usermanager and just copy and paste). Furthermore, you need to custom identity model to add UserRoles navigation property to add role usingHasData..., and a lot of issues.
I recommend you read carefully this page from MS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding
My solution is creating custom seeding logic, and I prefer to move them to a separated console app.

I'm already using this HasData method inside the SeedData method, So I've tried to use the old traditional way by adding new rows to the IdentityUser table, then adding rows to the IdentityRole table, then linking the users and the roles by adding new rows to the IdentityUserRole table.
But I'm afaird that I'm missing some underlinying action that is done when creating user or when hashing the password @NguyễnKỳDươngTrường

For more detail, if you enable AccountConfirmed, you should set EnmailConfirmed to true. Btw, UserManager and RoleManager tend to use Normalized{Object} instead of {Object}. Please set it to upper case too.

Injecting the service in the constructor would create a circular reference. When you are defining your model, the model doesn't exist. IMHO just add a startup test in your application; apply migrations, test if the table is empty, populate some defaults.

Try this:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    var userManager = this.GetService<UserManager>();
    ...

One thing though, I would do this on your IdentityDbContext implementation using HasData as suggested in one of the comments above NOT in the DbContext OnModelCreating ie.
public MyIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string> {
    
    public MyIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyIdentityDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
  
        SetupData(builder);
    }

    private void SetupData(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        // Users
        var defaultUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>() { 
            new ApplicationUser()
            {
                Id = "USER_HASH"
                Name = "name",
                Email = "SuperAdmin@system.com",
                NormalizedEmail = "SUPERADMIN@SYSTEM.COM",
                UserName = "username",
                NormalizedUserName  = "NormalizedUserName",
                UserType = UserType.WebsiteAdmin,
                // Use your known hash here (the hash below is for Password123!)
                PasswordHash = "PasswordHash",
                // Use your hash here
                SecurityStamp = "SecurityStamp",
                AccessFailedCount = 0,
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
                TwoFactorEnabled = false
            }
        };

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasData(defaultUsers);

        // Roles
        var defaultRoles = new List<IdentityRole>(){ 
            new IdentityRole { Id = "ROLE_HASH", Name = 
            RoleNames.WebsiteAdminRole, NormalizedName = 
            RoleNames.WebsiteAdminRole.ToUpper() }
        };

        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(defaultRoles);

        // User roles
        var defaultUserRoles = new List<IdentityUserRole<string>>(){ 
            new IdentityUserRole<string>(){
               Id = "USER_HASH",
               RoleId = "ROLE_HASH" 
            }
        };

        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(defaultUsersRoles);
    }

}

Note: The hash I have for the password above is with API set to use IdentityV3 ie.
builder.Services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options => options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV3);

You can create your own password hash using
var passwordHasher = this.GetService<IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser>>();
var passwordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, "YourPassword");


where would I put this instruction? inside SeedData constructor?
I've tried to put it there, but there is no GetService method defined for the SeedData class?

in OnModelCreating (or in a method in your implementation of DbContext). I have added an example to use the HasData method which I think is what you really should be doing though.

The issue you're facing is coming from mixing the concerns of database schema definition and user management within OnModelCreating. OnModelCreating is primarily designed to configure entities and relationships using Fluent API and isn't ideally used for operational tasks such as user creation. As you described you are trying to inject a UserManager directly into your DbContext can lead to dependency resolution issues because of circular dependencies and the way dependency injection scopes are managed in ASP.NET Core applications. Instead you could try to seed your data using separate seeding mechanism that runs after your database context is configured.
For that first create seeding class which is not dependent on the DbContext constructor:
public class SeedData
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public SeedData(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task SeedWebsiteAdminsAsync()
    {
        var superAdminLogin = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "username",
            Email = "youremail",
            UserType = UserType.WebsiteAdmin
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(superAdminLogin, "test");

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(superAdminLogin, RoleNames.WebsiteAdminRole);
        }

        // Additional logic for saving related data to the database
    }

    public async Task SeedCompanyAdminsAsync()
    {
        // Your logic to seed company admins
    }
}

In your Program.cs, configure your application to run the seeding after the application starts and after performing migrations. Remove Seed code from OnModelCreating.
